# Match anything in ( )

Tags: java, regex

This is my simplified regex:

```
abc\[(.+?)\]
```

I want to match like:

- `?text[.ev.wa.vew.av.ewa]` => `.ev.wa.vew.av.ewa`
- `?text[hello$(abc)elv]` => `hello$(abc)elv`
- `?text[just test[test]]` => `just test[test]`
- `?text[test 2[test]here something]` => `test 2[test]here something`

So,

- I want to match the `?text[`
- Then capture everything between square brackets into Group 1
- Then match everything after that.

Comment: So, match one or more `)`s, `abc\((.+?)\)+` or `abc\(([^()]*)\)+`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiże uh in a group

Comment: This is exactly the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72716201/regex-trying-matching-the-correct-format

Comment: That is actually not working.

Comment: Do you mean the `)`s must be in the capture? Just put the group boundary there, `abc(\([^()]*\)+)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew
I think this problem is so hard and confused
"abc(w)(wwww)). abc(wwww))" I hope it match "w)(wwww)"
Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe using the greedy quantifier? `abc\((.+)\)`?

Comment: Well, It matched to next match

Comment: It matched "w)(wwww)). abc(wwww)" in group

Comment: Ok, seems like you want to match any one or more substrings in between one or more `(` and `)`. Try ``abc((?:\(+[^()]*\)+)+)``, see https://regex101.com/r/YGBUur/2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245886/discussion-between-jin-tang-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: What you try to match is not a regular language on the [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\?text(?:\[([^\]\[]*)]|\(([^()]*)\)).+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ogXw4s/6). The results are either in Group 1 or Group 2 (you will need to check in the code).

*Details*

- `\?text` - a `?text` text
- `(?:\[([^\]\[]*)]|\(([^()]*)\))`  - one of the two alternatives:`

  - `\[([^\]\[]*)` - `[`, zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char
  - `|` - or
  - `\(([^()]*)\)` - `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `.+` - one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Now, if you need to support nested brackets, you would need a recursion support, but Java regex does not provide such an option. Hence, the only regex way is to hardcode nested level support. Here is an example with one nested level:

```
\?text(?:\[([^\]\[]*(?:\[[^\]\[]*][^\]\[]*)*)]|\(([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*)\)).+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ogXw4s/7). You can add more levels.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments below, try this: `abc\(([^)]+\)\([^)]+\))`

https://regex101.com/r/lC8UJb/2

Using negated character classes like `[^)]+` is a little safer thanks to `.*?` as it is more exact to what is usually desired.

Comment: Very close, but something wrong :(

Comment: abc(w)(wwww)). abc(wwww)).
I hope it match "w)(wwww)"

Comment: Or is there any method to do if starts with \ like \(
It will escape the ( then It won't be detect

Comment: and something after )?
If this will not work, I think I can try another way.
Escape the ( and )